# How to fetch all orders together in WooCommerce using their REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I'm using the `WooCommerce REST API PHP Client Library` to manage an external order system. The code I am using is as below:

```
<?php

require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );

$options = array(
    'debug'           => true,
    'return_as_array' => false,
    'validate_url'    => false,
    'timeout'         => 30,
    'ssl_verify'      => false,
);

try {

    $client = new WC_API_Client( 'https://your-store-url.com', 'ck_enter_your_consumer_key', 'cs_enter_your_consumer_secret', $options );

    $data = $client->orders->get();

?>
```

This code is only returning 10 orders, but I need all the records together as I want to show it in a datatable. I have searched and got one solution from [here](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/issues/171)

`$client->get_orders( array( 'filter[limit]' => 50 ) );`

but it's generating the following error

`Call to undefined method WC_API_Client::get_orders()`

Why is `get_orders()` undefined? What is the difference between `get_orders()` and `orders->get()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that orders are paginated to 10 items by default, try:

```
// @param null|int $id order ID or null to get all orders
// @param array $args acceptable order endpoint args, like `status`
$client->orders->get( null, [ 'per_page' => 100 ] );
```

`WC_API_Client` does not have `get_orders()` method, but `$client->orders` returns `WC_API_Client_Resource_Orders` instance with the appropriate `get()` method.

http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#parameters

Comment: still getting only 10 orders :(

Comment: Yes, I did not test this, try some other parameters like `page` just to see if it's a pagination issue or something else.

Comment: Getting next 10 orders using `$client->orders->get( null, [ 'page' => 2 ] )`

Comment: Try `posts_per_page = -1` or `posts_per_page = 100`

Comment: `posts_per_page = -1` and `posts_per_page = 100` both are not working